# How to make Photoshop jsx run faster by stop updating rendering when script is running

Tags: photoshop, jsx

I have a Photoshop jsx action to do a bunch of time-consuming jobs. I assume that it could be much faster if Photoshop stops rendering to screen on every action. So that Photoshop will show nothing until the script done.

Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can halt redrawing entirely, however, for big batch processes I always make sure to do `togglePalettes();` before and after the main code execution. This will hide all the tool palettes which should speed things up a bit by avoiding updating them while your script runs.